# Project deposit feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After asking [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/309176/116604) on EE forum concerning an aspect of my home project, I figure out that some peoples were interested by what I am planning to do. And maybe those people want to follow the project, to see how it grows.

So I thought that it may be a good idea to create a kind of new feature where people could deposit some file, introduce the project, explain what they are doing and why. Other people could ask the project owner about a specific part of the code, schematic, or overall system.

It doesn't look like anything existing on stack exchange so I'm pretty sure that won't be possible.. But still, I think it's a good idea :)

Comment: Its a good idea already done on EDA and ETO http://www.edaboard.com http://www.electro-tech-online.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're describing is a personal blog.

There are several places that offer free blog or project status hosting, as well as code hosting, but StackExchange is not one of them.

When you start your blog, feel free to link it in your profile.

Comment: Okay, I'll do what you suggest then :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that EE.SE is just a sub site of stackexchange programming time is split between all of the sites, its not likely that you'll get a new feature as it needs to work for most of the sites and needs to be maintained

What little of the sites that did have blogs have now had that [feature removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow) because they were not used.

You might want to poke around on the stack exchange meta to learn how things work globally.